# pyspark Do python processes on an executor node share broadcast variables in ram?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, shared-memory

I have a node that has 24 cores and 124Gb ram in my spark cluster. When I set the spark.executor.memory field to 4g, and then broadcast a variable that takes 3.5gb to store in ram, will the cores collectively hold 24 copies of that variable? Or one copy?

I am using pyspark - v1.6.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that PySpark doesn't use any form of shared memory to share broadcast variables between the workers.

On Unix-like systems broadcast variables [are loaded](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/python/pyspark/worker.py#L145-L154) in the main function of the worker which is called only [after forking](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/daemon.py#L157) from the daemon so there are not accessible from the parent process space.

If you want to reduce footprint of the large variables without using external service I would recommend using file backed objects with memory-map. This way you can efficiently use for example [NumPy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

In contrast native (JVM) Spark applications indeed share broadcast variables between multiple executor threads on a single executor JVM.